# Cloning root filesystem of a virtualbox partition

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I have a test virtualbox partition running CentOS 7. There are many configurations on this particular partition. Some particular configurations, I have forgotten.

I need to transfer this virtualbox partition onto 3 new computers. Note: NOT virtualbox images. Basically, have the 3 new computers run CentOS 7 in the exact same way.
What is the fastest and best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write the partition to the host disc and then just use rsync that, and run 3 in parallel, with a bit of luck your host only reads the data once from disc before putting it on the network. That worked well for me.

You can try to muck with broadcasting or setting up some torrent and have the other 3 machines seed each other, but I doubt that makes things much faster and has a lot of overhead unless you do this regularly.

Comment: There are at least two problems with this approach: (1) `rsync` doesn't handle boot sectors, and (2) concurrent I/O with virtual machines sucks.

Comment: @lcd047 AFAIK The boot sector is not part of a partition and the OP doesn't want the whole image only a partition. Anyway if the client would include the bootsector writing to the host dics, that can be synced without problem.

Comment: There is a boot sector that is at the beginning of the partition, and a partition sector that is at the beginning of the disk.  Both have to be initialized properly for the system to boot.  But you're right that the OP's question doesn't make any reference to booting.  I'd still expect all this to be a lot easier if done by physically moving disks rather than over network.  Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

1. Shutdown the machine you want to duplicate
2. Create a new machine
3. Add the virtual disk of the old machine to the new one
4. Boot the new machine and use `ddrescue` to create an image of the partition you want to duplicate
5. Transfer the image to a physical machine
6. Copy the image (again using `ddrescue`) to the disks of the new computers
7. Restore the old virtual machine and head for the pub.